# Output department and direct reports

Tags: powershell, report, output

I am trying to create an "initial" text file that will hold a script run of all users + department + direct reports. My next step after making this file is to create another file the same way but compare it to the original to see if the department for the users ever changed. (not sure yet how to compare the department value just yet)

My current issue is that the department, even though the process is identical to another program I have made in the past, won't print it. Furthermore, when it prints my direct reports it prints only the first one with the whole extension of CN=..., OU=... etc.

I want it to print this way:

```powershell
username | Department(extensionAttribute14) | Direct Reports (as a single string)
we38432 | IT-Security | cm03456: 04555a: ....etc
```

My original script used this code for department:

```powershell
$deps = Get-Aduser -filter {name -like *} -Properties name, extensionAttribute14 | Select name, extensionAttribute14 | Export-CSV $listing -notypeinformation
```

and this worked. I tried the `{name -like *}` but that gave me errors in my current program. I know the `Export-CSV` makes it work but I can't use this format anymore.

for the direct reports my original was this:

```powershell
foreach ($ID in $directReports){
    if ($ID -ne $Null){
    $directreports = get-aduser $ID
    $directreports.name | Out-File $output -Append 
}
```

This code printed line by line the direct reports but I want them all listed in the same excel cell when I send it there.

I have printed a listing of all the members in the past using ":" and it worked but it is not the case with the direct reports listing. I just get errors when I use this format from my other program:

```powershell
foreach ($member in $empty.members){
    $string = $member.substring(3,$member.indexof(",")-3)
    $members = $members + ":" + $string
}
```

I hope someone can help me with my two issues.

```powershell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$documentOld = "C:\Temp\Old_Supervisor_list_mo_yyyy.txt"

Clear-Content $documentOld

$Header = `
"User ID" <#+ "|" + `
"Department" + "|" + `
"Direct Reports"#>

$Header | Out-File $documentOld -Append

$Users = Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties name, Enabled, Manager, extensionAttribute14 | Select Enabled, name, Manager, extensionAttribute14

foreach ($user in $Users){
if ($user.enabled –eq $true) {
    $name = $user.name
    $directReports = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties directreports | Select -ExpandProperty directreports
    $department = $user.extensionAttribute14


foreach ($ID in $directReports){
if ($ID -ne $Null){
            $directreports = get-aduser $ID
 #           $string = $directreports + ":"

}#end if $ID
}#end foreach $ID

$listing = `
$name  + "|" +  $deparment + "|" + $directreports#$string

$listing | Out-File $documentOld -Append

}# end if
}# end foreach $user
```

Comment: What do these fields represent? `we38432 | IT-Security | cm03456: 04555a: ....etc`. I can assume one is username but I would like you to tell me to be sure. I ask because is your direct reports more than one person?

Comment: IT-Security is department and yes most of the usernames have more than one direct reports as listed like " " : " " @Matt

Comment: Do you know what your PowerShell version is? `Get-Host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let see if we can make this a little easier and efficient.

```powershell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$documentOld = "C:\Temp\Old_Supervisor_list_mo_yyyy.txt"

$Users = Get-AdUser -Filter *  -Properties name,Enabled,Manager,extensionAttribute14 | Where-Object{$_.Enabled}

$Users | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{
        Name = $_.Name
        Department = $_.extensionAttribute14
        DirectReports = ($_.Manager | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object{Get-Aduser $_ | Select-object -ExpandProperty Name}) -join ":"
    }

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props

} | Select-Object Name,Department,DirectReports | Export-CSV -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation -Path $documentOld
```

First we get all the users from your directory with `Get-AdUser -Filter *` taking all the properties outside the norm that we want. Since you just wanted accounts that are enabled we filter those out now with `Where-Object{$_.Enabled}`.

The fun part is creating the custom object array ( which is necessary for input for `Export-CSV`). Create a small hashtable called `$props` where we set the properties by their friendly names. The special one being `DirectReports` where we take all the users manager DN's ( Assuming they have one where is what `Where-Object{$_}` does by filtering out nulls/empty strings.) and use `Get-Aduser` to get there names. Since you could have more than one manager an array is most likely returned we use `-join` to ensure only a single string is given for the `DirectReports` property. That property collection is created for every user and it is then used to create a `New-Object` which is sent to the output stream.

The `Select-Object` that follows is just to ensure the order of columns in the CSV that is created. No need for making a CSV file with lots of `Out-File`s when `Export-CSV` and `-Delimiter "|"` will do the hard work for you.

Comment: I get the following error: Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'E
xport-CSV'.

I am also not familiar with the [pscustomobject]@ code

Comment: Saw the 2.0 comment and updated. Try again with the new non-typoed code

Comment: When I made the changes, I get pages of errors saying:  
    `Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is 
null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.`

Comment: I had removed where `$users` was generated in an edit. Please try again. This tested OK for me.... nvm something is wrong. On the users that have the error do they not have a manager?

Comment: My errors don't show which user has it: `Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is 
null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
\Supervisor_oldFile2.ps1:51 char:64
+         DirectReports = ($_.Manager | ForEach-Object{Get-Aduser <<<<  $_ | Se
lect-object -ExpandProperty Name}) -join ":"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingV 
   alidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Activ 
   eDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser`

Comment: The code prints but gives me manager not direct reports ... hmmm

Comment: Try this iteration. Accounts for potential nulls in manager. Sorry about the back and forth

Comment: Ok I will play with your code to get a better understanding since your formatting is something I am not familiar with. I will also see if I can also incorporate how to include the direct reports too. Thanks :)

Comment: Let me know if you have more questions. Could always start a chat

Comment: Thanks @Matt . If I get confused over what is going on in the code I will make sure to take you up on your offer.

Comment: @narue1992 I updated the answer to give a little more explanation.