# How to separate an array of canonical names?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am unable to take the `directReports` property of a manager and iterate over each username. They come out as an array of canonical names.

How can i get these names in a  way i can iterate over them and use `Set-ADUser`?

```
$people.Split(" ,", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

This gives me lines with each section of the canonical name

like

```
CN=USER
OU=PLACE
OU=MOREPLACE
```

Each user is separated by ", ".

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You might find the [ForEach statement](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html) to be useful

Comment: If you *showed* us what your input and your desired output look like we *might* be able to help you get from one to the other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815126/output-department-and-direct-reports that is an example of iterating over each manager of a user. For the purpose of creating csv output but the logic is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`directReports` the AD property is not Canonical name, but an array of Distinguished names. Distinguished name is an acceptable Identity for the AD cmdlets. Lastly, You don't need to split at all since it's already an array, just use `ForEach-Object`

```
Get-ADUser ExampleManager -Properties directReports |
    Select -ExpandProperty directReports |
    ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser $_ ...}
```

Comment: Thanks, got Canonical and Distinguished confused.